# Как посчитать длину введенного числа?

Tags: c

Есть задача

> Надо ввести строку **пример: 100** и посчитать длину строки **ответ : 3**

Как этого достичь ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос из заголовка:
Для целых чисел достаточно подсчитать, сколько раз число разделится на 10, пока не станет нулём

На вопрос из тела поста ответ, очевидно, `strlen`

Answer (score -1):

Вот ответ (я бы сказал не лучший )

```
// 1. подключить библиотеки
// 2. считать строку
// 3. превращаем строку в число
// 4. число превратить в строку
// 5. вывести длину строки

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N 10

int main()
{
    char s[256];    // сюда вводим
    char buffer[256];  // а здесь считаем длину

    int x; int err =0;
    bool test_fgets=true;

    do
    {

        // этот блок для того чтобы отлавливать такие "исключения": вводим 33223йцу, а выводит 33223
        do{
            printf("\nВведите целое число :");

            test_fgets=true;
            fgets(s,N,stdin);
            for(int i=0;s[i]!='\n';i++){
                if(test_fgets==true)
                    if(s[i]<'\x30' || s[i]>'\x39'){
                        printf("Ошибка. Повторите ввод!\n"); test_fgets=false;}
            }
        } while(test_fgets!=true);
        // ---

        err=sscanf(s, "%d",&x);
        if (err!=1)
            printf("\n Ошибка ввода. \n ");

    } while (err!=1);

    printf("\n Введено целое число : %d ", x);

    sprintf(buffer, "%d", x);
    // itoa(x, buffer, 10); у меня не заработала
    x = strlen(buffer);
    printf("\n Длина числа : %d \n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]